# Django PUT/PATCH request body is empty in RetrieveUpdateAPIView

Tags: django, django-request

I'm trying to update user by passing Jwt token in header. But body of my request is empty.

View passes empty data to serializer.

**views.py**

```
class UserRetrieveUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    renderer_classes = (UserJSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_data = request.data.get('user', {})
        print(f'request data: {request.data}') # prints empty dic {}
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            request.user, data=serializer_data, partial=True
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I run PUT or PATCH request on Postman, I get unchanged user which is related to a token.

postman:
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEWS0.png)

django terminal says:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJXtM.png)

> Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

**UPD:**

I don't know why, but django can't receive '{' in PUT request.

I echoed in [postman-echo.com/put](http://postman-echo.com/get).
It responded the same body I sent.

[Echo of PUT request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSIWX.png)

How to make Django accept '{' at the beginning of a request body?

Answer (score 0):

it happen to me as well, following a tutorial, so i replaced this:

```
serializer_data = request.data.get('user', {})
```

with just this:

```
serializer_data = request.data
```

seems to work (at least for me),hope that helps.

Comment: Didn't help. Still getting empty dictionary with the same curly brackets error in terminal...